# Snow fall this Christmas near Hong Kong?

Tags: hong-kong, snow

What is the nearest place from Hong Kong (within Mainland China) where one could see snowfall around Christmas?

Comment: Nearest by distance, or by travel time on a given mode of transport?

Comment: by distance, i wish to take a train from Shenzen

Comment: Not quite a dupe, but close enough to be interesting: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/21041/closest-skiing-to-indochina

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yulong Mountain in Yunnan Province, Xiling Snow Mountain Ski Resort in Sichuan Province.  Maybe some of the other mountains in those two provinces as well.