# Is it necessary to book trains in the Jungfrau region?

Tags: trains, public-transport, switzerland, jungfrau-region

**Information**

I will be staying in Interlaken with 4 whole days to kill from the 25th of this month.

I would like to do some hiking in the region. For example, getting day-return train tickets to Grindelwald and/ or to Lauterbrunnen.

I would also like to have a trip up to Jungfraujoch.

**Questions**

Firstly, is it advisable to book (either of) these journeys in advance? If so, how far in advance and by what means?

**Extra information**

I have read in the "Rough Guide to Europe on a Budget" that to get to Jungfraujoch it is better in their opinion to take cable cars. I am happy to either and so the above questions really apply twice: to trains and to cable cars.

Note: I have an InterRail pass.

Comment: [This swis RailPass and discounts question](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/17113/what-rail-cards-passes-discounts-should-visitors-to-switzerland-be-aware-of) might help you with the rail tickets part

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no need to book anything in advance here. Go to the station, buy a ticket and take the train. After checking at [interrail.eu](http://www.interrail.eu/countries/switzerland/trains-switzerland), it seems that the trains from Interlaken to Grindelwald and Lauterbrunnen are not included in the pass.

There is no cable car to the Jungfraujoch. You have to take a train from Grindelwald or Wengen to the [Kleine Scheidegg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleine_Scheidegg) station. From there you proceed by a second train to the so-called top of Europe. Both these trains are [rack railways](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rack_railway). Maybe the author of the "Rough Guide" was a bit imprecise on that ... Note that the Jungfrau railway is not included either in your Interrail pass.