# Summer skiing in Norway

Tags: norway, skiing

I've heard it's possible to go summer skiing in Norway.

Is this correct and where should I go if I want to visit these attractions?

Comment: @Karlson It's not a duplicate. I can't see anything about Norway.

Comment: Now there is an answer about Norway, so we can close it :) http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/12936/ski-resorts-during-the-northern-hemispheres-summer/17233#17233